# Symfony query builder with post submit data is not changing the values in EventListener

Tags: symfony, post, submit, query-builder, event-listener

I have a filter form which is filtering for markets, types and airlines. When submitted, I'd like another dropdown (documentlist) to be filtered after the selected values. Therefore I created a post_submit eventlistener which is working (I dumped the values as you can see in the following code). But when then trying to update the documentlist values through a query builder and with the data from my filters, it's not working. Any ideas:

```
    <?php

namespace DocumentBundle\Form\Document;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use DocumentBundle\Form\Document\DocumentFilterType;

class DocumentDeactivationType extends DocumentFilterType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {

    $builder
    ->add('type', 'choice', array('choices' => array(
        'document_types.contract' => 1,
        'document_types.general'=>2,
        'document_types.goodwill_policy'=>3,
        'document_types.pricesheet'=>4,
        'document_types.yq_update'=>5,
        'document_types.contract_addendum'=>6),
        'choices_as_values' => true, 'label' => 'label.types',
        'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'label.type', 'required' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'Documents'))

    ->add('airlines', 'entity', array(
      'class' => 'AppBundle:Airline', 'property' => 'id',
      'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er){

        return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
          ->addOrderBy('a.id', 'ASC');
        },
      'choice_value' => 'id',
      'choice_label' => 'id', 'label' => 'label.airlines',
      'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'required' => false,
      'translation_domain' => 'Documents'))

    ->add('markets', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Market', 'property' => 'id',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er){
          return $er->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->addOrderBy('m.id', 'ASC');
          },
        'choice_value' => 'id',
        'choice_label' => 'id', 'label' => 'label.markets',
        'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true, 'required' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'Documents'))

    ->add('documentlist', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'DocumentBundle:Document',
        'property' => 'name',
        'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'label.document_list',
        'empty_value' => "Select document",
        'required' => false,
        'mapped' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'Documents'));

  $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder)
      {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        $markets = $data['markets'];
        $type = $data['type'];
        $airlines = $data['airlines'];
        dump($markets, $type);
$builder
    ->add('documentlist', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'DocumentBundle:Document',
        'property' => 'name',
        'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'label.document_list',
        'empty_value' => "Select document",
        'required' => false,
        'mapped' => false,
        'translation_domain' => 'Documents',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($markets, $type, $airlines){
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->where('e.markets = :markets')
        ->andWhere('e.airlines IN (:airlines)')
        ->andWhere('e.products IN (:products)')
        ->setParameter('e.markets', $markets)
        ->setParameter('e.airlines', $airlines)
        ->setParameter('e.type', $type);
      },
      ));
  });
}
public function getName()
{
  return 'document_deactivation';
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the form (add or remove fields) in a `POST_SUBMIT` event. But you can in a `PRE_SUBMIT` event, so you just need to change `POST_SUBMIT` with `PRE_SUBMIT`.

But be careful because your form data won't be normalized in `PRE_SUBMIT`, so you will have to work with raw data from your form (an array), or to normalize manually your data.

Comment: I'm sorry I only understood half of your answer. I understand that I can't change it on POST_SUBMIT so I changed it to PRE_SUBMIT. But what about the normalizing part? I don't understand that :/ Now with the PRE_SUBMIT event, I still get the data from my filter but the dropdown is still not updating it's values..

Comment: Sorry to distrub you again but do you have any further advise? I'm still stuck on that..